# how to emit error then emit the cached data using RxJava?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, mvp

I am using RxJava in a MVP solution and I want to achieve this scenario:

- try to get the server data and if its successful populate the view using **server data**
- if its unsuccessful for any reason (no internet - server unreachable - server internal error) **show the appropriate message** but also populate view with the **cached data**.

constraints:

- I don't wanna use any extra callback (RX can do it all)
- I don't wanna access local repo directly from Presenter

what I tried:

in my Repo:

```
    override fun getRepos(userName: String, page: Int, pageSize: Int):Observable<List<Repo>> {

 return githubRemoteService.getReposList(userName, page, pageSize)
                .subscribeOn(schedulersProvider.ioThread())
                .flatMap { repos ->
                    val mappedRepos = remoteResponseMapper.mapRepoResponse(repos)
                    githubLocalService.saveRepos(mappedRepos)
                    Observable.just(mappedRepos)
                }
 .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.just(githubLocalService.getReposList(userName, page, pageSize)))
               .observeOn(schedulersProvider.mainThread())

    }
```

in my presenter:

```
githubInteractor.getRepos(userName, page, pageSize).subscribe(
            { repos ->
                 showReposInView(repos)
            },
            { error ->
                digestAndShowErrorInView(error)  //the problem is here - no error will be present here
            })
```

as we know when I use `onErrorResumeNext`, the observable source changes but **the error will never be emitted**.

how can I emit the error first and then emit local repo data ?

if it cant be done like this, how can I change my scenario to get the same scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `onError` and continue the stream. `onError` means a critical error occurred and the `Observable` ends. You can't use it.

There is a simple solution. You can wrap your result in a structure that indicates error/data. E.g.

```
sealed class MyData
data class Success(val data: List<Repo>) : MyData
data class Error(val t: Throwable): MyData
```

The you can map the successful API response to `Success` and in case of error (in `onErrorResumeNext`) you can create an `Error` class and use `concat` to continue with the local repo list.

This way you get both errors and success in `onNext` and you don't break the chain.

In `onNext` you can use `when` and handle error/success appropriately.

Comment: i know I cant. never tried to do that. i am looking for a workaround to acheive that scenario.

Comment: your solution will work. i actually saw that in a medium post. im hoping a more clear and neat solution if available.

Comment: https://rongi.github.io/kotlin-blog/rxjava/rx/2017/08/01/error-handling-in-rxjava.html  I think there must be a better way than these.

Comment: @AmirZiarati what is so bad in this way?

Comment: checking the object type and casting the response every where. i dont say this is bad but I say there may be a better way. if I dont find any other better approach im gonna accept this.

Comment: cant I start emitting from both observable at the same time (local and remote) ? or emit the local first then I go for remote ? then If some error happend getting the remote it will be emitted. or any other way there must be some better way than wrapping your object by some class

Comment: @AmirZiarati you don't cast it, the kotlin compiler does the casting for you (using `when`). For your second comment doesn't that change your logic?

Comment: i know about the smart cast and all. no I just want to do some best practice.